# How to distinguish two different types of hashtable

Tags: java, generics

I have a method which have two parameter e.g.

```
computHash(HashTable hs, String myName){
    //compute hs data, it traverse the hashtable and create xml
    return xmlString;
}
```

I have a class named Record,

```
Class Record
{
    String Name;
    String FName;
    String Phone;

    //and its setter and getter.
}
```

Now what I want that if I pass `Hash` of `<String, Record>` then I want to create xml according to the  record class member. and If I pass `<String, String>` then I create simple xml.
Can I do it like `"instance of"` keyword or not, if yes then how.

Comment: And why don't you create two different methods, since you want to do two different things?

Comment: @JBNizet Two methods with 2 different parameterized types won't be valid overload.

Comment: @RohitJain: agreed, but overloading is not required.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah of course. I guess that would be better option.

Comment: Apart from the obvious issue, why are you using a `Hashtable` instead of a `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to detect the type of the `HashTable` itself. This information is not present in the compiled code, which is called [`Type Erasure`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) . What you can do is detect the type of one of the values inside the `HashTable`. Unfortunately this does not work for an emtpy `Hashtable`.

Answer (score 1):

Generics only exists during compile time, there is no way to distinguish between a `HashTable<String, Record>` and a `HashTable<String, String>` without looking at the entries.

You have to get an entry and can then do an `instanceof` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, if this was what you were asking about:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hashtable<Integer, String> table1 = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
        table1.put(0, "String");
        Hashtable<Integer, Record> table2 = new Hashtable<Integer, Record>();
        table2.put(0, new Record());
        System.out.println("Table 1:");
        someFunction(table1);
        System.out.println("Table 2:");
        someFunction(table2);
        Hashtable<Integer, Integer> table3 = new Hashtable<>();
        System.out.println("Table 3:");
        someFunction(table3);
    }

    static void someFunction(Hashtable hash) {
        if (hash != null && hash.size() > 0) {
            Object o = hash.elements().nextElement();
            if (o instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("It's a String!");
            } else if (o instanceof Record) {
                System.out.println("It's a Record!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("It's an empty table and you can't find the type of non-existing elements");
        }
    }
}

class Record {
    String Name;
    String FName;
    String Phone;

    // and its setter and getter.
}
```

Edit: as pointed out by someone else, the Hashtable can not be empty. Then you would need to do something like I just edited in